# Facing issue configure spring batch admin in spring boot-Cannot resolve the name 'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-jmx

```
 We need spring batch admin UI to monitor jobs. we are creating spring boot application to create and schedule batch runs on daily
basis. once am running boot application below exception is coming and try to comment with jmx-context xsd and got connection time out with
below exception.
```

---

```
 Below error is coming from logs files.


    [jar:file:/C:/Users/janakpa/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-admin-manager/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.3.1.RELEASE-sources.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/integration/jmx-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd;
     lineNumber: 308; columnNumber: 73; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the
     name 'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup' to a(n) 'attribute
     group' component.
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
     ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
     ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
     ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
     ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
     ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:233)
     ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
                ... 29 common frames omitted
             Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup' to a(n)
     'attribute group' component.
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
     Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown
     Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
     Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(Unknown
     Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown
     Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown
     Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
                at co
```

Spring batch admin --jmx-context.xml getting parsing issue.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

```
<int-jmx:mbean-export id="integrationMBeanExporter" default-domain="spring.application" server="mbeanServer" />
```

POM file below are dependency used for spring integration ,spring batch admin spring batch core and Spring batch infrastructure ..etc

```
  <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
                <classifier>sources</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                <version>12.1.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jmx</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version></version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-oxm -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>


Below is my main class code and improt xml files from spring batch admin in spring boot main class.



    @SpringBootApplication
                                @EnableIntegration
                                @EnableIntegrationMBeanExport
                                @ImportResource({ "classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml",
                                        "classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml"
     })
                                 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BatchAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                                        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })

         public class BatchprocessApplication {

                            public static void main(String[] args) {


                   SpringApplication.run(BatchprocessApplication.class, args);

                 }

                                    }
```

Comment: HI Siong,This is due to spring integration core dependency ?

Comment: Added POM XML in Question.

Comment: I think Spring Batch Admin is not compatible with Spring 5.x

Comment: I am using ENVIRONMENT : oracle .                                                                     I need only JDBC oracle item reader and item writer but it asking for file directory.                                                                                                            can we disable file context in spring admin batch or spring batch.. ?
batch.job.configuration.file.dir=target/config
batch.job.service.reaper.interval=60000